# jQuery cleanup task

Tags: jquery, html

So this may be a little tricky, but take a look at the div below. I need some jQuery code that is going to go through this div, and delete the rows OR the cells that contain a textbox or a dropdown, or really any kind of input field, WITHOUT any data in it, or just a blank choice ("" or " "). It would also need to delete the corresponding label, for example in the case

```
    <td>
    Account Number
</td>
<td>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.STPData.BorrowerAccountNumber, new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "STPData.BorrowerAccountNumber", onchange = "this.value = ConvertToPasswordCharacters(this.value, '*', 4);UpdateField(this);" }) %>
    </td>
```

If that above textbox didn't have any data in it, I wouldn't want to see the cell that contained the text 'Account Number' either. Any ideas? I know this is really tricky, might need like a jQuery expert here.

```
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr id="tr5">
        <td style="text-align: right;">
            Indication Nickname:
        </td>
        <td id="IndicationNickname" colspan="3">
            Swap
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                Legal Name of the Borrower
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <select class="BorrowerLegalNameID" id="BorrowerLegalNameID" name="BorrowerLegalNameID" onchange="UpdateField(this, false);ShowBorrowerLegalName();" propertyname="BorrowerLegalNameID"><option value=""></option>
                    <option value="new borrower">Create a new borrower</option>
                    <option value="0|441185|1001 Cassatt, LLC">1001 Cassatt, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|190215|1100 Township Line Road Associates, LLC">1100 Township Line Road Associates, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|871197|1102 West Street Limited Partnership">1102 West Street Limited Partnership</option>
                    <option value="0|879123|1165 Busch Real Estate Associates, LLC">1165 Busch Real Estate Associates, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|440595|1210 American Boulevard LP">1210 American Boulevard LP</option>
                    <option value="0|441188|252 Realty Partners">252 Realty Partners</option>
                    <option value="0|876775|2617 HP Associates">2617 HP Associates</option>
                    <option value="0|884742|3 Seasons, LLC">3 Seasons, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|884223|3L Realty, LLC">3L Realty, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|440988|760 Sproul Road Delco LP">760 Sproul Road Delco LP</option>
                    <option value="0|770259|805 Henderson Blvd. Associates, L.P.">805 Henderson Blvd. Associates, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|440948|901 Market, LLC">901 Market, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|871026|A. Duie Pyle">A. Duie Pyle</option>
                    <option value="0|885770|Achristavest, LLC">Achristavest, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|876662|Acquire Land, L.P.">Acquire Land, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|886621|Allentown Refrigerated Terminals, Inc.">Allentown Refrigerated Terminals, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|884116|Allentown Refrigerated Terminals, Inc.; G &amp; H International Traders, Inc.; Sel, Inc.; Uniq ...">Allentown Refrigerated Terminals, Inc.; G &amp; H International Traders, Inc.; Sel, Inc.; Unique Brokera...</option>
                    <option value="0|883807|American Infrastructure">American Infrastructure</option>
                    <option value="0|876241|American Infrastructure, Inc. and Subsidiaries">American Infrastructure, Inc. and Subsidiaries</option>
                    <option value="0|441014|American Infrastructure, LLC">American Infrastructure, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|883188|Applewood Lumber Supply Company">Applewood Lumber Supply Company</option>
                    <option value="0|770115|Atlantic Paper Company">Atlantic Paper Company</option>
                    <option value="0|441207|Atlantic Trailer Leasing Corporation">Atlantic Trailer Leasing Corporation</option>
                    <option value="0|870247|Audubon Ventures II, LLC">Audubon Ventures II, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|879076|AVL Real Estate Associates, LLC">AVL Real Estate Associates, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|887667|B &amp; G Coastal Enterprises, Inc., William A. Gibbs, Jr., and Raymond C. Shockley">B &amp; G Coastal Enterprises, Inc., William A. Gibbs, Jr., and Raymond C. Shockley</option>
                    <option value="0|880491|B&amp;G Equipment Company">B&amp;G Equipment Company</option>
                    <option value="0|882948|Barnes Associates - I">Barnes Associates - I</option>
                    <option value="0|877884|Bayview Crossing, LLC">Bayview Crossing, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|441148|Beacon Revex, LLC">Beacon Revex, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|877762|Beaver Brook Crossing, LLC">Beaver Brook Crossing, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|887877|Bentley Family Partnership I, L.P.">Bentley Family Partnership I, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|888740|Bernstein-Ryan, LLC.">Bernstein-Ryan, LLC.</option>
                    <option value="0|888845|Berwind Property Group, Inc.">Berwind Property Group, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|440483|Bestfield Properties, LLC">Bestfield Properties, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|873569|BJH Properties, Inc">BJH Properties, Inc</option>
                    <option value="0|883906|Brackenville Crossing, LLC">Brackenville Crossing, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|884234|Brandywine Country Club">Brandywine Country Club</option>
                    <option value="0|883937|Brothers, Inc.">Brothers, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|884895|Bryn Eyre, L.P.">Bryn Eyre, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|440460|Burris Logistics">Burris Logistics</option>
                    <option value="0|441186|Cassford Associates">Cassford Associates</option>
                    <option value="0|887627|CD Gaither Associates, LLC">CD Gaither Associates, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|887643|CD Lincoln Associates, LLC and CD 2000 Lincoln Associates, LLC">CD Lincoln Associates, LLC and CD 2000 Lincoln Associates, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|882854|Chapman Lane Investors, LP">Chapman Lane Investors, LP</option>
                    <option value="0|888310|Chichester Business Park, LLC">Chichester Business Park, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|884123|Chincoteague Hotel, LC">Chincoteague Hotel, LC</option>
                    <option value="0|441194|Coin Automatic Laundry Equipment Co.">Coin Automatic Laundry Equipment Co.</option>
                    <option value="0|879273|Cornell &amp; Company, Inc.">Cornell &amp; Company, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|873492|Country Day School">Country Day School</option>
                    <option value="0|5831|Country Day School at Overbrook">Country Day School at Overbrook</option>
                    <option value="0|885461|Croftley Properties, Inc.">Croftley Properties, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|886910|D.B.R., LLC">D.B.R., LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|886168|Dann Fleet, LC">Dann Fleet, LC</option>
                    <option value="0|885550|DBW Enterprises, LLC">DBW Enterprises, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|5978|DCI-800 Devon Park Drive, L.P.">DCI-800 Devon Park Drive, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|441015|DDLM, LP">DDLM, LP</option>
                    <option value="0|879887|Delaware Hospice">Delaware Hospice</option>
                    <option value="0|441334|Delcard Associates, Inc.">Delcard Associates, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|879272|Delor D'Andrea Cornell">Delor D'Andrea Cornell</option>
                    <option value="0|885068|Deluca Lot Investors, L.P.">Deluca Lot Investors, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|770103|DKM Associates">DKM Associates</option>
                    <option value="0|888368|East Coast Ag Holdings, Limited Partnership">East Coast Ag Holdings, Limited Partnership</option>
                    <option value="0|875452|Eastern Athletic Clubs Realty LLC">Eastern Athletic Clubs Realty LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|873841|Eastern Warehouse Distributors, Inc">Eastern Warehouse Distributors, Inc</option>
                    <option value="0|885345|Endless Pools">Endless Pools</option>
                    <option value="0|885768|Eustace W. Mita">Eustace W. Mita</option>
                    <option value="0|440539|Evergreen Equipment Leasing Co., Inc.">Evergreen Equipment Leasing Co., Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|872146|Finnaren &amp; Haley">Finnaren &amp; Haley</option>
                    <option value="0|884561|FR Gordon Property Holding LP and Gordon Drive Holdings I, LLC">FR Gordon Property Holding LP and Gordon Drive Holdings I, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|441252|Frank W. Winne Co., Inc.">Frank W. Winne Co., Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|440991|Fraternal Properties, LLC">Fraternal Properties, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|886247|Frederick W. Hertrich, IV &amp; Christopher Hertrich">Frederick W. Hertrich, IV &amp; Christopher Hertrich</option>
                    <option value="0|879521|Fusco Properties, LP">Fusco Properties, LP</option>
                    <option value="0|440875|Gary T. and Ann Nolan">Gary T. and Ann Nolan</option>
                    <option value="0|440116|Gary T. Nolan">Gary T. Nolan</option>
                    <option value="0|886399|George Krapf, Jr. and Sons, Inc.">George Krapf, Jr. and Sons, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|440523|Glenwood One, LLC">Glenwood One, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|878606|Green Homes Real Estate, LP">Green Homes Real Estate, LP</option>
                    <option value="0|873539|Gretz Beverage Bucks, Inc.">Gretz Beverage Bucks, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|873538|Gretz Beverage Montco, Inc.">Gretz Beverage Montco, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|872798|H.P. Cadwallader, Inc.">H.P. Cadwallader, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|876293|Hair Systems, Inc.">Hair Systems, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|885325|Hankin Eagleview Associated, LP">Hankin Eagleview Associated, LP</option>
                    <option value="0|190204|Hankin Eagleview Associates">Hankin Eagleview Associates</option>
                    <option value="0|440692|Hat Wit One LLC">Hat Wit One LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|886410|Haverford Reserve, LP">Haverford Reserve, LP</option>
                    <option value="0|878097|Heritage Dairy Stores, Inc">Heritage Dairy Stores, Inc</option>
                    <option value="0|877765|Hockessin Village Center, LLC">Hockessin Village Center, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|883640|Holly Oak Crossing, LLC">Holly Oak Crossing, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|888332|IFURS Holdings, Inc.">IFURS Holdings, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|884184|Image First Atlanta, LLC">Image First Atlanta, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|884508|Image First of SE Florida, LLC">Image First of SE Florida, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|441286|Image First Uniform Rental Service, Inc. &amp; Image First Professional Apparel, Inc.">Image First Uniform Rental Service, Inc. &amp; Image First Professional Apparel, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|888205|Ivymont Gloucester Township Associates, L.P.">Ivymont Gloucester Township Associates, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|770295|J&amp;L Building Materials, Inc.">J&amp;L Building Materials, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|874199|James A. Perdue">James A. Perdue</option>
                    <option value="0|883789|Jenbrooke Properties, Inc">Jenbrooke Properties, Inc</option>
                    <option value="0|440587|Jesters Corner, L.L.C.">Jesters Corner, L.L.C.</option>
                    <option value="0|874922|John Rock, Inc.">John Rock, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|873643|K &amp; R Leasing Co.">K &amp; R Leasing Co.</option>
                    <option value="0|886289|K.W. Lands, L.L.C.">K.W. Lands, L.L.C.</option>
                    <option value="0|441095|K.W. Lodging, L.L.C.">K.W. Lodging, L.L.C.</option>
                    <option value="0|884069|Kent Narrows Hotel, LLC">Kent Narrows Hotel, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|770286|Kinsale Properties LLC">Kinsale Properties LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|879191|Krishnas, LLC">Krishnas, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|884735|L&amp;W Partners, L.P.">L&amp;W Partners, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|885685|Lambdin Development Limited Liability Company">Lambdin Development Limited Liability Company</option>
                    <option value="0|877766|Laurel Crossing, LLC">Laurel Crossing, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|440878|Liborio LP">Liborio LP</option>
                    <option value="0|441483|Main Line Watercraft Realty LP">Main Line Watercraft Realty LP</option>
                    <option value="0|190041|Mark and Ruth Handler">Mark and Ruth Handler</option>
                    <option value="0|883330|McElderry Bloomberg, LLC">McElderry Bloomberg, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|882986|Midway Realty Corporation">Midway Realty Corporation</option>
                    <option value="0|886290|Modern Mushroom Farms, Inc.">Modern Mushroom Farms, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|871668|Myers Family Partnership">Myers Family Partnership</option>
                    <option value="0|872463|MZ 9285, LLC">MZ 9285, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|872973|National Label Company">National Label Company</option>
                    <option value="0|887793|NB Partners, LLC">NB Partners, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|876344|NH &amp; MP Properties, L.P.">NH &amp; MP Properties, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|875343|O.P. Schuman and Sons, Inc.">O.P. Schuman and Sons, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|884115|Orefield Cold Storage and Distribution, Inc.">Orefield Cold Storage and Distribution, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|871220|Parkway Gravel, Inc.">Parkway Gravel, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|890862|Pavilion East Associates, L.P. - WT">Pavilion East Associates, L.P. - WT</option>
                    <option value="0|877761|Penn Green Crossing, LLC">Penn Green Crossing, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|877764|Pennsville Crossing, LLC">Pennsville Crossing, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|886352|Pennsylvania Machine Works, Inc. and Texas PMW, Inc.">Pennsylvania Machine Works, Inc. and Texas PMW, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|440185|Philmont Associates, L.P.">Philmont Associates, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|888303|Pohlig at Haverford Reserve, L.P.">Pohlig at Haverford Reserve, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|888808|Pre Holding Hampstead LLC">Pre Holding Hampstead LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|890868|PREIT Associates, L.P. - WT">PREIT Associates, L.P. - WT</option>
                    <option value="0|873682|Preston A Schell &amp; R. Justin Healy">Preston A Schell &amp; R. Justin Healy</option>
                    <option value="0|873457|Quinn Family Restaurants LLC">Quinn Family Restaurants LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|440946|Red Mill Square, LLC">Red Mill Square, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|886274|RER, LLC">RER, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|440501|Reybold Venture Group IV LLC">Reybold Venture Group IV LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|440800|Ribon Partnership, LTD">Ribon Partnership, LTD</option>
                    <option value="0|440184|RMF Associates">RMF Associates</option>
                    <option value="0|886470|Route 73 Express Car Wash LLC">Route 73 Express Car Wash LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|190218|Rumsey Electric Company....">Rumsey Electric Company....</option>
                    <option value="0|885659|Salisbury Lodging, LLC">Salisbury Lodging, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|883739|Seaford Commons, LLC">Seaford Commons, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|884020|Semanoff, Ormsby, Greenberg &amp; Torchia, LLC">Semanoff, Ormsby, Greenberg &amp; Torchia, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|883509|Sher-Rockee Mushroom Farms, LLC">Sher-Rockee Mushroom Farms, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|440945|Shipyard Center, LLC">Shipyard Center, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|877885|Shoppes of Mount Pleasant, LLC">Shoppes of Mount Pleasant, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|877763|Shoppes of St. Georges, Inc.">Shoppes of St. Georges, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|440457|Shoreline Grading Inc.">Shoreline Grading Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|885360|Sleep Tight, LLC">Sleep Tight, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|886509|Sora Housing, LLC">Sora Housing, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|875174|Southdown Homes, LP">Southdown Homes, LP</option>
                    <option value="0|441060|St. Michaels Equity, LLC">St. Michaels Equity, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|877636|Stephen A. Thorne">Stephen A. Thorne</option>
                    <option value="0|885627|Stoltzfus Property Management, LLC">Stoltzfus Property Management, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|440586|Stoney Creek Plaza LLC">Stoney Creek Plaza LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|883508|Storage Partners of Cherry Hill, LLC">Storage Partners of Cherry Hill, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|883849|Storage Partners of Exton, LP">Storage Partners of Exton, LP</option>
                    <option value="0|441216|Tague Family Limited Partnership">Tague Family Limited Partnership</option>
                    <option value="0|876244|Tague Lumber, Inc.">Tague Lumber, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|881423|The California Mushroom Farm">The California Mushroom Farm</option>
                    <option value="0|883503|The Myers Family Partnership II, LP/ A. Ross Myers">The Myers Family Partnership II, LP/ A. Ross Myers</option>
                    <option value="0|887978|The Sands Incorporated">The Sands Incorporated</option>
                    <option value="0|883542|Thomas Automotive">Thomas Automotive</option>
                    <option value="0|883641|Townsend Crossing, LLC">Townsend Crossing, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|887573|Traditions of America, L.P.">Traditions of America, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|883607|Trion Group Inc.">Trion Group Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|190201|United Electric Supply Company, Inc.">United Electric Supply Company, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|877767|Upper Chi Crossing, LLC">Upper Chi Crossing, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|441169|Urie and Blanton Inc. ......">Urie and Blanton Inc. ......</option>
                    <option value="0|883795|V&amp;N">V&amp;N</option>
                    <option value="0|887774|Vandemark &amp; Lynch, Inc. and V D &amp; L Holdings, Inc.">Vandemark &amp; Lynch, Inc. and V D &amp; L Holdings, Inc.</option>
                    <option value="0|884105|Village of Five Points Ventures, LLC">Village of Five Points Ventures, LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|875937|Washington West Associates, L.P.">Washington West Associates, L.P.</option>
                    <option value="0|876845|West North LLC">West North LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|870541|Wilkinson Heritage, L.L.C.">Wilkinson Heritage, L.L.C.</option>
                    <option value="0|884485|William S. Vail">William S. Vail</option>
                    <option value="0|884803|WKG Schafer">WKG Schafer</option>
                    <option value="0|875138|Worth and Worth New Jersey LLC">Worth and Worth New Jersey LLC</option>
                    <option value="0|440750|Worth and Worth Partnership">Worth and Worth Partnership</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;" class="BorrowerLegalName">
            <td colspan="4">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input class="economicTextBox" id="Borrower_CompanyName" name="Borrower.CompanyName" onchange="UpdateField(this);" propertyname="Borrower.CompanyName" style="width: 560px;" value="" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                ASC 820 Credit Spread (bps)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="economicTextBox" id="STPData_DerivativeCreditSpread" name="STPData.DerivativeCreditSpread" onchange="UpdateField(this);" propertyname="STPData.DerivativeCreditSpread" value="" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                Date Borrower ISDA was signed
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="economicTextBox hasDatepicker" datatype="Date" id="STPData_BorrowerIsdaSignedDate" name="STPData_BorrowerIsdaSignedDate" onchange="parseAndSetDt(this); " propertyname="STPData.BorrowerIsdaSignedDate" value="" type="text"><img title="..." alt="..." src="http://localhost/Extranet/Img/icon_frequency2.gif" class="ui-datepicker-trigger">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Payment Method
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="STPData_PaymentMethodID" name="STPData.PaymentMethodID" onchange="UpdateField(this);" propertyname="STPData.PaymentMethodID"><option value=""></option>
                    <option value="6701">Check</option>
                    <option value="6704">Debit Account</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="6700">Debit DDA</option>
                    <option value="6702">Settle with Branch</option>
                    <option value="6703">Wire Transfer</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                Borrower Valuation Report Interval
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="STPData_BorrowerReportInterval" name="STPData.BorrowerReportInterval" onchange="UpdateField(this);" propertyname="STPData.BorrowerReportInterval"><option value=""></option>
                    <option value="5650">Monthly</option>
                    <option value="5651">Quarterly</option>
                    <option value="5652">SemiAnnually</option>
                    <option value="5653">Annually</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Account Number
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="economicTextBox" id="STPData_BorrowerAccountNumber" name="STPData.BorrowerAccountNumber" onchange="this.value = ConvertToPasswordCharacters(this.value, '*', 4);UpdateField(this);" propertyname="STPData.BorrowerAccountNumber" value="" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                Internal Reference Number
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="economicTextBox" id="STPData_InternalReferenceNumber" name="STPData.InternalReferenceNumber" onchange="UpdateField(this);" propertyname="STPData.InternalReferenceNumber" value="" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                Loan Reference Number
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="economicTextBox" id="STPData_LoanReferenceNumber" name="STPData.LoanReferenceNumber" onchange="this.value = ConvertToPasswordCharacters(this.value, '*', 4);UpdateField(this);" propertyname="STPData.LoanReferenceNumber" value="" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" id="ContactsForBorrower">
                <b>Contacts</b>
                <table id="BorrowerContactsGrid" class="resultsGrid" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td class="resultsSubHeader">
                            Name
                        </td>
                        <td class="resultsSubHeader">
                            Type
                        </td>
                        <td class="resultsSubHeader">
                            Payment Notice Delivery
                        </td>
                        <td class="resultsSubHeader">
                            Borrower Report Delivery
                        </td>
                        <td class="resultsSubHeader">
                            Fax Number/Email Address
                        </td>
                        <td id="Action" class="resultsSubHeader">
                            Action
                        </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6">
                                No Contacts
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody></table>


            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: It's not terribly tricky at all, but it would be helpful if you could describe **exactly** which elements should be removed based on which other elements. How would the code decide whether to remove a row, or a cell? Also, please post the **actual markup** you're working with in the browser, and not the server-side code that generates it.

Comment: 1. open http://www.jsfiddle.com 2. paste your HTML code into the HTML section 3. press "Tidy up" 4. paste the formatted code here

Comment: @Sime - Posted the tidied up HTML.
@Matt - Actual markup added

Comment: @Matt - there are 8 pairs of Label - input. legal name, asc, date, payment method, borrower valuation, account #, internal #, loan #

Comment: @slandau There are no LABEL elements in your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('table').find('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
    if ( !$.trim(this.value) ) {
        $(this).closest('td').remove();
    }
});
```